# How to copy a file from local to Dockerfile to run in the build id

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, ubuntu, dockerfile

I need to copy a file from local to Dockerfile. I need to copy a python file from local to inside of a docker image to run a pyspark application.

Docker is placed in

mkdir -p /root/temp/dockerTest/
cd /root/temp/dockerTest/

DockerFile content's

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN mkdir -p /usr/soft/bin/temp/
RUN cd /usr/soft/bin/temp/
RUN wget "https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz"
RUN tar -xzvf spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN rm -r spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
RUN mkdir -p /usr/inputFiles/
RUN cd /usr/inputFiles/
RUN wget "https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/data/sdss6949386.csv" 
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN cd /usr/local/bin
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python
RUN pip install pyspark
RUN mkdir -p /usr/soft/inputFilesConatiner 
CMD cp /usr/soft/inputFilesConatiner/test.py /usr/soft/bin/temp/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/test.py
CMD /usr/soft/bin/temp/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 1g --driver-cores 1 --driver-memory 1g test.py
```

Docker is built by :

cd /root/temp/

docker build dockerTest

```
CMD cp /usr/soft/inputFilesConatiner/test.py /usr/soft/bin/temp/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/test.py
```

docker run -t -i (id)

it throw's error.

I need to copy the file from local to dockerImage or session.

Can you folks help we with this?

Comment: What is the error

Comment: You probably want the COPY command.

Comment: Refer to the best practices here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy and it would depend on your use case. For simple file copy, Docker COPY is preferred. If you want yo extract your files from an archive use ADD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dockerfile add:

```
ADD /path/to/local/file /path/inside/docker
```

or

```
COPY /path/to/local/file /path/inside/docker
```